# É possivel bloquear acesso a uma rota com middlewares?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, middleware

Gente, tenho uma pasta public com todos os arquivos "publicos" do meu site html,css,js etc. E outra pasta chamada private com todos os arquivos privados arquivo de conexao com banco de dados e etc, que é uma rota só para mim que sou admin poder acessar ela, e quero saber se posso bloquear o acesso a essa rota para em caso de um usuario comum tente acessar esta rota private ele nao consiga.Ate agora eu consegui criar middlewares, mas nao sei nem por onde começo, meu arquivo app.js esta assim ate agora:

```
 const express = require("express")
 const handleBars = require("express-handlebars")
 const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
 const app = express()
 const admin = require("admin")
 const path = require("path")

 //Configuções
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})
 app.use(bodyParser.json())

 //Handlebars
 app.engine('handlebars',handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main' }))
 app.set('view-engine', 'handlebars')

 //Public
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "public")))

 app.use((req,res,next) => {
  console.log("Middleware rodando")
  next()
 })

 //Rotas
 app.get("/", (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html")
 })

 app.use('/admin', admin)

 const PORT = 3000
 app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log("Servidor rodando")
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função responsável por verificar se o usuário é admin e utilizar ela como *middleware*, por exemplo:

```js
const adminOnly = (req, res, next) => {
    // Verifique qual usuário está enviando o request
    if (usuario === admin) {
        // Se ele for admin, você chama o próximo middleware
        next();
    } else {
        // Status 401 = Unauthorized (não autorizado)
        res.status(401).send();
    }
}

app.use('/admin', adminOnly, admin);
```

Desse modo, ao mandar uma requisição para as rotas que são tratadas pelo seu `admin`, passarão antes pelo *middleware* `adminOnly`. Se o usuário não for um admin, receberá uma resposta `401`, caso contrário, segue o seu fluxo normal (dentro do seu arquivo `admin.js`).

Para mais informações sobre *middlewares* no Express, veja o [site oficial](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) com alguns exemplos.

---

Detalhe: você pode organizar isso em pastas:

- `/routes` para os arquivos responsáveis pelo roteamento do seu app.
- `/controllers` para os arquivos que irão realizar os métodos necessários, como consultas ao banco e ter o `res.send()`.
- `/middlewares` para os arquivos responsáveis pela autenticação e autorização das rotas.

Isso deixa um projeto mais organizado do que colocar tudo no seu arquivo principal, mas você aprende com o tempo.

Comment: Obrigado! conseui fazer algo parecido a partir dái.

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode fazer algo do tipo

```
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
 try {
    // validaçao
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Auth'});
  }
}



//Rotas
app.get("/", middleware, (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html")
 })
```

Comment: 401 ou 403,  dependendo do problema. Excessões não é o melhor jeito de tratar esse tipo de erro